# Typescript: Get data outside of Observable

Tags: angularjs, typescript, observable, httprequest, subscribe

I tried to send an HttpRequest in Typescript. I need to store the recieved data outside of the subscribe function. But when I want to print the user variable outside of the subscribe, it is `undefined`.
In the subscribe function it works fine. So how I can get access to the data outside of the subcribe function?

```
private user: User;

public sendHttpLogin(username: string, password: string) {

  this.http.get<User>('http://localhost:8080/login?password='+password+'&username='+username).subscribe(data => {
    //save the data on a User Object
    this.user = data;
    //this works fine
    console.log(this.user)
  });

  //this is undefined
  console.log(this.user);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

The second `console.log` gets called before the `http.get` has returned anything, so that's why it's undefined.

Your first `console.log` is correct, you can only use the data once it has returned from the `get` function.

You could call another function there to continue the flow of your application.

```
private user: User;

public sendHttpLogin(username: string, password: string) {

  this.http.get<User>('http://localhost:8080/login?password='+password+'&username='+username).subscribe(data => {
    this.continueApp(data)
  })
}

private continueApp(data){
    this.user = data
}
```